# File/Property rename problem in Visual Studio and Explorer

Tags: visual-studio

I am running Windows 7.
In Visual Studio, if I try to rename a file by right-click/rename, it behaves as normal for a couple of seconds, then switches out of edit mode.
A similar problem occurs when I try to change a property, for example the name of a control. When I click in the property value, I can start editing, but then it assumes the edit is complete, and if I continue typing it overwrites the text. It does this every couple of seconds, so, for example, if I want to name a control mnuFile, I might get mn, then uFi, then le. S, the control ends upgetting called whatever I typed in the last 2-3 characters.
I have the same problem with file rename in Explorer.
Looks to me as though some timeout is kicking in and terminating the edit.

---

Well, I was going to try a 'Repair install', but that's not an option in Windows 7! So, I went through the re-install, up to the point where I thought is was going to trash my install, and then cancelled it! By some miracle, that has fixed the problem!#Thanks for the advice about ShellExView, I'll try that next time it happens.

---

Thanks for the answers guys! In my view it is more a Visual Studio issue, since it affects both file renames and properties in VS. In Explorer it only affects file rename, which is (just slightly) less annoying!

Comment: I've voted to move this question to superuser.com because that site is for more general computer questions. stackoverflow is specifically programming related questions.

Comment: @Simon - on the other hand, this is a dev-IDE question; not sure that fits "general".

Comment: @Marc - yeah I thought that, but he said he had the same problem with file rename in explorer. It doesn't seem that programming related either.

Comment: Any chance some key on your keyboard got stuck?

Comment: Personally, I think anything related to VS belongs here. "General" users don't usually use it in any context, and it eases up searches for people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess this is a problem with an explorer shell extension.You can check out what extensions you have installed using a tool like [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Try disabling them one at a time and see if you still get the problem.

(I had a issue similar to this once with the dropbox client)